# Имена всех столбцов страницы

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Как с помощью ClosedXml получить список всех используемых столбцов таблицы excel? Так выдаются столбцы для  всех ячеек. Подходящего метода только для столбцов не нашел

```cs
var cells = source_sheet.CellsUsed();
foreach (var c in cells)
{}
```

UPD. Уточню: на скрине необходимые заголовки таблицы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD1. Вытащил используемые столбцы так. Но выглядит как-то... не очень =)

```cs
List<string> names = new List<string>();
var cells = sheet.CellsUsed();
foreach(var c in cells)
{
    if (names.Contains(c.Address.ColumnLetter))
        break;
    else
        names.Add(c.Address.ColumnLetter);
}
```

Comment: `source_sheet.HeadersRow().CellsUsed()`

Comment: @aepot, забавно, но метода ``HeadersRow()`` нет ни в Worksheet, ни в Workbook

Comment: Ну тогда так https://stackoverflow.com/a/65581982/12888024

Comment: @aepot, тоже  видел этот пост, но это поиск по конкретному столбцу. И так можно взять первый или последний столбцы. Уточнил задачу